# Disable Screenshot/Record on Cordova iOS app

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap

We developed Phonegap app and we have lots of videos. So, we want users to prevent taking screenshots or recording. There are few plugins but it doesn't work on iOS.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-prevent-screenshot
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-privacyscreen

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have other plugins that work on ios like this one for example :

https://github.com/devgeeks/PrivacyScreenPlugin

If it ever has a problem (it was not tested under iOS13) you can use this plugin which does not prevent the screenshot but blurs app content when it goes into the background to prevent legibility of sensitive information.

https://github.com/lifeofcoding/cordova-blur-app-privacy-screen

Comment: This only prevents the App Switcher to show sensitive data, right. It doesn't prevent screenshot

Answer (score 0):

In the iOS version, it is still not possible to block the screenshots for mediation, so improvements were made on an existing plugin ( PrivacyScreenPlugin - https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-privacyscreen?activeTab=code ) to make the print black.

```html
/**
 * PrivacyScreenPlugin.m
 * Created by Tommy-Carlos Williams on 18/07/2014
 * Copyright (c) 2014 Tommy-Carlos Williams. All rights reserved.
 * MIT Licensed
 */
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "PrivacyScreenPlugin.h"

static UIImageView *imageView;

@implementation PrivacyScreenPlugin

- (void)pluginInitialize
{
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onAppDidBecomeActive:)
                                               name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onAppWillResignActive:)
                                               name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil];

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onAppDidFinishLaunching:)
                                                 name:UIApplicationDidFinishLaunchingNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)onAppDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
  if (imageView == NULL) {
    self.viewController.view.window.hidden = NO;
  } else {
    [imageView removeFromSuperview];
  }
}

- (void)onAppWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
  CDVViewController *vc = (CDVViewController*)self.viewController;
  NSString *imgName = [self getImageName:self.viewController.interfaceOrientation delegate:(id<CDVScreenOrientationDelegate>)vc device:[self getCurrentDevice]];
  UIImage *splash = [UIImage imageNamed:imgName];
  if (splash == NULL) {
    imageView = NULL;
    self.viewController.view.window.hidden = YES;
  } else {
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:[self.viewController.view bounds]];
    [imageView setImage:splash];
    
    #ifdef __CORDOVA_4_0_0
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:imageView];
    #else
        [self.viewController.view addSubview:imageView];
    #endif
  }
}

// Code below borrowed from the CDV splashscreen plugin @ https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen
// Made some adjustments though, becuase landscape splashscreens are not available for iphone < 6 plus
- (CDV_iOSDevice) getCurrentDevice
{
  CDV_iOSDevice device;
  
  UIScreen* mainScreen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
  CGFloat mainScreenHeight = mainScreen.bounds.size.height;
  CGFloat mainScreenWidth = mainScreen.bounds.size.width;
  
  int limit = MAX(mainScreenHeight,mainScreenWidth);
  
  device.iPad = (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad);
  device.iPhone = (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone);
  device.retina = ([mainScreen scale] == 2.0);
  device.iPhone4 = (device.iPhone && limit == 480.0);
  device.iPhone5 = (device.iPhone && limit == 568.0);
  // note these below is not a true device detect, for example if you are on an
  // iPhone 6/6+ but the app is scaled it will prob set iPhone5 as true, but
  // this is appropriate for detecting the runtime screen environment
  device.iPhone6 = (device.iPhone && limit == 667.0);
  device.iPhone6Plus = (device.iPhone && limit == 736.0);
  
  return device;
}

- (NSString*)getImageName:(UIInterfaceOrientation)currentOrientation delegate:(id<CDVScreenOrientationDelegate>)orientationDelegate device:(CDV_iOSDevice)device
{
  // Use UILaunchImageFile if specified in plist.  Otherwise, use Default.
  NSString* imageName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"UILaunchImageFile"];
  
  NSUInteger supportedOrientations = [orientationDelegate supportedInterfaceOrientations];
  
  // Checks to see if the developer has locked the orientation to use only one of Portrait or Landscape
  BOOL supportsLandscape = (supportedOrientations & UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape);
  BOOL supportsPortrait = (supportedOrientations & UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait || supportedOrientations & UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown);
  // this means there are no mixed orientations in there
  BOOL isOrientationLocked = !(supportsPortrait && supportsLandscape);
  
  if (imageName) {
    imageName = [imageName stringByDeletingPathExtension];
  } else {
    imageName = @"Default";
  }

  // Add Asset Catalog specific prefixes
  if ([imageName isEqualToString:@"LaunchImage"])
  {
    if(device.iPhone4 || device.iPhone5 || device.iPad) {
      imageName = [imageName stringByAppendingString:@"-700"];
    } else if(device.iPhone6) {
      imageName = [imageName stringByAppendingString:@"-800"];
    } else if(device.iPhone6Plus) {
      imageName = [imageName stringByAppendingString:@"-800"];
      if (currentOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || currentOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        imageName = [imageName stringByAppendingString:@"-Portrait"];
      }
    }
  }
  
  BOOL isLandscape = supportsLandscape &&
  (currentOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || currentOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
  
  if (device.iPhone5) { // does not support landscape
    imageName = isLandscape ? nil : [imageName stringByAppendingString:@"-568h"];
  } else if (device.iPhone6) { // does not support landscape
    imageName = isLandscape ? nil : [imageName stringByAppendingString:@"-667h"];
  } else if (device.iPhone6Plus) { // supports landscape
    if (isOrientationLocked) {
      imageName = [imageName stringByAppendingString:(supportsLandscape ? @"-Landscape" : @"")];
    } else {
      switch (currentOrientation) {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
          imageName = [imageName stringByAppendingString:@"-Landscape"];
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    }
    imageName = [imageName stringByAppendingString:@"-736h"];
    
  } else if (device.iPad) { // supports landscape
    if (isOrientationLocked) {
      imageName = [imageName stringByAppendingString:(supportsLandscape ? @"-Landscape" : @"-Portrait")];
    } else {
      switch (currentOrientation) {
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
        case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
          imageName = [imageName stringByAppendingString:@"-Landscape"];
          break;
          
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
        case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
        default:
          imageName = [imageName stringByAppendingString:@"-Portrait"];
          break;
      }
    }
  }
  
  return imageName;
}

- (void)onAppDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // Este método será chamado quando o aplicativo for inicializado
    NSLog(@"O aplicativo foi inicializado!");
    
    // Aqui você pode chamar a função makeSecure
    [self makeSecure];
}

- (void) makeSecure {
    // Código para chamar makeSecure
    UIWindow *window = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController].view.window;

    UITextField *field = [[UITextField alloc] init];

    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, field.frame.size.width, field.frame.size.height)];

    UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"whiteImage"]];
    image.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height);

    field.secureTextEntry = YES;

    [window addSubview:field];
    [view addSubview:image];

    [window.layer.superlayer addSublayer:field.layer];
    [[field.layer.sublayers lastObject] addSublayer:window.layer];

    field.leftView = view;
    field.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
}


@end
```